# Matching "last-line" of a dd in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a inline ul inside a dd element, which shows like this,

[image]

Now I'm trying to match the "second" line with selectors, is that even possible?

Items on each line varies (depends on the screen size) so I can't just match them when I print them in PHP.

### Why I'm doing this:

I have a `margin-bottom` defined for all `li`, I'm trying to remove that for items in the "last-line", otherwise there would be extra margins.

Attached a minimal example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Title:</dt>
                        <dd>
                            <ul class="list-inline">
                                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to know when it's collapsed down...All I can think of is explicit setting rows.

Comment: please tell me what do you think about my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible with javascript/jQuery. you said you want it based on screen size so you have to call function every time the screen changes.

The way i see it done is:

get the screen size and start looping the li elements by saving their widths in temporary variable, when this variable value becomes higher than the screen size, break and apply to next li the margin.

EDIT:

Noticed the responsive classes on div, so for this way -  just take the div's width and not the screen size.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                <dl>
                    <dt>Title:</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <ul id="li_container" class="list-inline">
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

for start add id to the ul "li_container"

then with jQuery :

```
  function fix_margins(){
       $("#li_container li").css("margin-bottom","your_default_margin_goes_here"); // reset margins
       var container_width = $("#li_container").outerWidth();
       var temp_width = 0;
       var i=1;
       $.each($("#li_container li"),function(){
          temp_width += $(this).outerWidth();
          if(temp_width > container_width) 
          {
             $("#li_container li:nth-child("+(i)+") ").nextAll().css("margin-bottom","0"); // remove bottom margins for all in second row
             return false;
          }else {i++;}
        });
   }
$(document).ready(function(){
    fix_margins();
    $( window ).resize(function() { 
       fix_margins();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match on a "last line", even more so in this case because it is dynamic. But you could apply a negative `margin-bottom` to the `ul` to *cancel out* the `li` margins:

```css
.container {
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.container ul {
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}

.container ul li {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">
            <dl>
                <dt>Title:</dt>
                <dd>
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item</a></li><li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>Some other content</div>
```